# AWS Lex v2 bot response card giving error on twilio

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio, amazon-lex

Problem statement: I want to access Lex V2 chatbot with response card buttons on WhatsApp.

I created a Lex V2 bot, and created a channel for Twilio. Connected Twilio through WhatsApp, and able to use my bot fine for plaintext responses. But in my bot, I also return a response card with buttons for one of the slot values. This works fine on AWS console, but when I run it through Twilio, it gives error saying response body is empty, or too big. Sharing my lambda code below. Please help on how to make it work?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    //console.log("EVENT = ", event);
    const sessionState = event['sessionState'];
    const sessionAttributes = sessionState['sessionAttributes'];

    const location = get_slot(event, 'Location');
    const checkInDate = get_slot(event, "CheckInDate");
    const nights = get_slot(event, "Nights");
    const roomType = get_slot(event, "RoomType");
    
    const response = "Booking completed for location = " + location +
        ", checkInDate = " + checkInDate +
        ", nights = " + nights +
        ", roomType = " + roomType;

    console.log('slots = ', response);

    if(!roomType){
        const message = {
                'contentType': 'ImageResponseCard',
                "imageResponseCard": {
                    "title": "Room Type",
                    "subtitle": "Select your room preference",
                    //"imageUrl": "",
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "text": "King",
                            "value": "king"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Queen",
                            "value": "queen"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Deluxe",
                            "value": "deluxe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            };
        /*const message =  {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'select room king.q'
        };*/    
        return elicit_intent(event, sessionAttributes, message);
    }
    
   const message =  {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': response
        };
    return close(event, sessionAttributes, message);
};

function close(intent_request, session_attributes, message) {
    intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['state'] = "Fulfilled";
    return {
        'sessionState': {
            'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
            'dialogAction': {
                'type': 'Close'
            },
            'intent': intent_request['sessionState']['intent']
        },
        'messages': [message],
        'sessionId': intent_request['sessionId'],
        'requestAttributes': intent_request['requestAttributes'] 
    };
}

function elicit_intent(intent_request, session_attributes, message){
    intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['state'] = "InProgress";
    return {
        'sessionState': {
            'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
            'dialogAction': {
                'type': 'ElicitSlot',
                "slotToElicit": "RoomType",
            },
            'intent': intent_request['sessionState']['intent']
        },
        'messages': [message],
        'sessionId': intent_request['sessionId'],
        'requestAttributes': intent_request['requestAttributes']
    };
}

function get_slot(intent_request, slotName) {
    const slots = intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['slots'];
    if(slots[slotName] && slots[slotName].value && slots[slotName].value.interpretedValue){
        return slots[slotName].value.interpretedValue;
    }
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API for WhatsApp currently only supports [messages with buttons via registered template messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).

Once your template with buttons has been approved, you can send buttons as part of your WhatsApp messages. To send a button, you need to send a message that contains the body of the template. The buttons are automatically appended to the message.

In your case, you will need to send a message body so that the template can be matched and include the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. So I just return some text from my chatbot, and configure Twilio to render buttons for that text right?

Comment: I believe so, but you will be limited to returning the exact text required by the template (with substitutions, of course).

Comment: Any update of this problem? It's possible to send a response card without template messages?